# Check is destination directory exist then proceed if not then create it and proceed afterwards

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button on one of the worksheets that lets user to continue with his task to save his/her template as a separate workbook in the folder.

Here is my code

```
Private Sub ContinueButton_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Sheets(cmbSheet.Value).Visible = True
    Application.Goto Sheets(cmbSheet.Value).[a22], True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Now what I need is to check if that folder exist, in case if the folder does not exist my user should be able to create it.

My code to create this folder is here below, but how to connect this 2 functions together I simply have no idea, since I am fairly new to VBA

```
Sub CreateDirectory()
Dim sep As String
sep = Application.PathSeparator
'sets the workbook's path as the current directory
ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
MsgBox "The current directory is:" & vbCrLf & CurDir
'makes new folder in current directory
MkDir CurDir & sep & Settings.Range("C45").Value
MsgBox "The archive directory named " & Settings.Range("C45").Value & " has been created. The path to your directory " & Settings.Range("C45").Value & " is below. " & vbCrLf & CurDir & sep & Settings.Range("C45").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am going to modularize your code a little bit:

First get the directory path here

```
Function getDirectoryPath()
    getDirectoryPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Settings.Range("C45").Value
End Function
```

You can create the directory using this function

```
Sub createDirectory(directoryPath)
    MkDir directoryPath
End Sub
```

You can check if a directory exists or not using `Dir` function

```
Dir(directoryPath, vbDirectory) 'empty string means directoryPath doesn't exist
```

The final function on button click:

```
Private Sub ContinueButton_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Sheets(cmbSheet.Value).Visible = True
    directoryPath = getDirectoryPath
    'Creating the directory only if it doesn't exist
    If Dir(directoryPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
         createDirectory directoryPath
    End If
    Application.Goto Sheets(cmbSheet.Value).[a22], True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but where all this has to go, my original button is in Module 5, do I have to place all code above in the same Module?

Comment: Can't say much unless we see your code. However, In excel you can put the first two functions in any module and it would be accessible elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, thanks, let me give it a try, will get back to you in few minutes

Comment: All worked nicely!, one simple question, where should I place MsgBox, to let User know the location of the folder?

Comment: Well! That depends on when do you want the user to know. If you want to show the user that the directory has been created, you should put it in `createDirectory`. If you want to show the user in which directory the template is going to be saved, put it on button click just before `Application.Goto`.

Comment: Actually in 2 places, first to let them know that folder does not exist and second once it has been created with destination address, before clicking "Continue", I mean this >>> Application.Goto Sheets(cmbSheet.Value).[a22], True

Comment: Also, End If was missing, please update so the others can benefit from this too

Comment: I was looking for a way to check if the directory exists that didn't involve FileSystemObject - thanks for providing one.

Comment: Be sure to use Dir("SomeDirectory",vbDirectory) . If you just use Dir("SomeDirectory") by itself, you will find directories that contain files, but will not find directories that do not!

Answer (score 0):

I created a macro that will save as pdf certain tabs of my excel in a relative (variable)folder.
It will use the contract reference to create a subfolder, such subfolder label is exactly the contract reference. If subfolder already exists it just creates the files in it, else (subfolder does not exist) then it creates the folder and save the files in it.

```
Sub Gera_PDF_MG_Nao_Produtor_Sem_Ajuste()

    Gera_PDF_MG_Nao_Produtor_Sem_Ajuste Macro



    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim LaudoName As String
    Dim NF1Name As String

    MyFolder = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & Sheets("Laudo").Range("C9")
    LaudoName = Sheets("Laudo").Range("K27")
    NF1Name = Sheets("MG sem crédito e sem ajuste").Range("Q3")

    Sheets("Laudo").Select
    Columns("D:P").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

If Dir(MyFolder, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
    Sheets("Laudo").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=MyFolder & "\" & LaudoName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False

    Sheets("MG sem crédito e sem ajuste").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=MyFolder & "\" & NF1Name & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False

Else
    MkDir MyFolder
    Sheets("Laudo").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=MyFolder & "\" & LaudoName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False

    Sheets("MG sem crédito e sem ajuste").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=MyFolder & "\" & NF1Name & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False

End If

    Sheets("Laudo").Select
    Columns("C:Q").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Range("A1").Select



'
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

```
If Dir(Fldrpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir Fldrpath
End If
```

**Fldrpath** refer to the Folderpath if Folder not found **MkDir** creates the folder

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't just dump your code here, try to add a brief explanation to it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer