# Download files from google drive renaming with name based on a column of a spreadsheet

Tags: sh

He had created a form on google drive where he would collapse a series of information and the person would submit a photo. But google drive saves the files with the date and time of file upload and user logged in google. I already needed the files to have the name based on one of the submitted columns.

I need a code that downloads this image that is in the folder of the drive, and that changes the name of them by the value of a column in specific, someone can create in some language something of the type?

My excell worksheet has the following structure

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>column_A </th>
    <th> column_B </th>
    <th> column_C </th>
    <th> column_D </th>
    <th> column_E_file_name </th>
    <th> column_F </th>
    <th> column_G </th>
    <th> column_H </th>
    <th> column_I </th>
    <th> column_J </th>
    <th> column_K </th>
    <th> column_L_link_of_drive </th>
    <th> column_M</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>14/02/2018 19:06:40 </td>
    <td>Name completed 1 </td>
    <td>RG 1 </td>
    <td>birth date 1 </td>
    <td>N USP 1 </td>
    <td>b- </td>
    <td>Graduação </td>
    <td>EESC</td>
    <td> email1@gmail.com </td>
    <td>fone</td>
    <td> 2014 </td>
    <td>https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Gx2fA6mrI7eDxZvE1CgW_8BElTgglDzi</td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>14/02/2018 19:06:42 </td>
    <td>Name completed 2 </td>
    <td>RG 2 </td>
    <td>birth date 2 </td>
    <td>N USP 2 </td>
    <td>A- </td>
    <td>Graduação </td>
    <td>EESC </td>
    <td> email1@gmail.com </td>
    <td>fone</td>
    <td> 2013 </td>
    <td>https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Gx2fA6mrI7eDxZvE1CgW_8BwlTgglDzi</td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This "column_L_link_of_drive" and the link of the file that the person uploaded in the response of the form, and is saved all a folder in the specific drive, I need the photos to have the name with value that is in column "column_E_file_name" and not the file upload date and time as goolge forms does by default.

**UPDATE**

I have a bash code that I download from my spreadsheet in .csv format and it pecens the separating lines in columns, I tried to use the wget command to download the file and save the name, but it does not save something with an image in a yes file corrupted with .jpg extension

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=data.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "The spreadsheet should be downloaded in csv format with the following name $INPUT"; exit 99; }
while read column_A column_B column_C column_D column_E_file_name column_F column_G column_H column_I column_J column_K column_L_link_of_drive column_M
do
        echo "Download file $column_E_file_name.jpg (Name: $column_B, USP number: $column_E_file_name, id: $column_L_link_of_drive)"    
        wget -o "$column_E_file_name.jpg" "$column_L_link_of_drive"
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: People ask questions here, I don't see any in the text.

Comment: Please, ask specific and precise programming related questions and not "someone can create something" questions here. Anyway, try to have a look at this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742636/download-pictures-from-url-and-save-in-a-folder-named-by-a-cell)