# Downloading png to disk creates broken file

Tags: ms-access, url, ms-access-2016

In my project, I want to download a png file from a url and save it to disk.

I have a url to an image, and I can load it in my web browser without any problem.
But when I use Access to download this file and save it, it saves "a" file, but it doesn't seem to have any image.  Every file it creates is 167kb, and I cannot view them with my graphics viewers (XnViewMP, for example).

When I load the created file with PE Studio, it says the MZ signature is missing (I'm not sure that means anything).

I've tried this with an .ico file on my local webserver, too, and have the same issue.

Here is the code I'm using to download the image file.

```
Public Function DownloadFile(whaturl As String, whatdestination As String) As Boolean

    Dim newfilepath
    Dim success As Boolean

    Dim WinHttpReq: Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", whaturl, False
    WinHttpReq.Send

     If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Dim oStream: Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.type = 1    '1 is binary
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody

        oStream.SaveToFile whatdestination, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
        success = True
    Else
        success = False
    End If

    DownloadFile = success

End Function
```

Maybe someone can tell my why this code seems to fail in downloading the png file?  I've tried with an .ico file, too, and have the same problem.  Maybe someone can help me with this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download pictures from url and save in a folder named by a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742636/download-pictures-from-url-and-save-in-a-folder-named-by-a-cell)

Comment: There is no code on that post that shows how to download a png from a url, and no answer there as to why my code here in this post does not work as expected.  I need help with the code I've posted.  I appreciate the thought though, but no, that doesn't help.  Can you show me why my code might fail?

Comment: My question is about the code I've posted and why it doesn't work.

Comment: That other question is about determining whether the destination folder exists.  This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Right, but it apparently has successful download code.

Comment: It uses an external library.  And it's not a duplicate of my question.
As for a sample url, you may use a url that leads to any png file.  For example: https://battlecats-db.imgs-server.com/u438-1.png

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Can you provide a url for testing with?

Comment: I think SE hid the https part from the link text.  You can use *any* .png url.  (how do I get that "suggested question" thingy off my post?

Comment: Did you edit that comment, don't think link was there when I first read it. I will see what I can do. Original posters can delete question or comment.

Comment: I tried your url and get 'no permission' error. I found an image url in another forum thread showing virtually this same code. That does not error but output is as you describe, not a viewable file. Sorry, got nothing else.

Comment: I assume this is likely due to you using the ancient Microsoft.XMLHTTP (version unspecified so v1) library, instead of a more recent version or WinHTTP.

Comment: Your code should work fine, assuming your URL is accessible without login/redirects etc.

Comment: The link is fine - if you click on it, you can open in the browser without issue and without any login or redirect.  Tell me why my link doesn't work for you.  @ErikA yes, it's true I'm using the XMLHTTP, but when I try the WinHTTP it doesn't work (will have to try it again to get details).

Comment: My problem is not so much with XMLHTTP (while I do prefer WinHTTP because XMLHTTP tends to be very much state-dependent), my problem is the undefined version of it you're using (instead of fixing it at 6.0) which means you might be using a very old version with no support for GZIP/Deflate which can cause this error (I can't investigate as the URL is not publicly available).

Comment: I still don't understand how the url cannot be publicly available.  I can load it my browser by clicking on it, and I don't need to login to view it - and I can do it in any browser.  I've tried with other images on my local network and they have the same problem when I try to download those.

Comment: Maybe you are onto something though; I tried with another png file at http://www.dcmembers.com/bgmcoder/wp-content/uploads/sites/32/2020/01/Systemus.png and that one downloads fine if I change the agent to *MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0* (thanks for that idea).  I still don't understand why my original link doesn't work, though.  Although, when I run that original link in Access VBA, I *do* get a popup saying "This page is accessing information not under it's control. Do you want to continue" - maybe the security issue is blocking the download even though I click "yes" ?

Comment: That URL is blocked by SecureDNS as a site holding nasty stuff. Staying off is a good advice.

Comment: It's just fetching image files; besides, my code only saves the image if the response is a 200 - which means it's connecting.  Still, if I can load the image in my browser and download it, why can't I do it with the code?

Comment: Okay, I tried downloading the original image file with autohotkey and it doesn't download either.  So it's got some kind of block, as you say - strange I can load it in the browser, though.

Comment: @ErikA The answer is, you are right, that the url is being blocked.  The code I posted is fine.  Can you propose an answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

You are making it too hard. Use a function like this:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' API declarations.
'
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "Urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) _
    As Long

' Download a file or a page with public access from the web. 
' Returns 0 if success, error code if not. 
' 
' If parameter NoOverwrite is True, no download will be attempted 
' if an existing local file exists, thus this will not be overwritten. 
' 
' Examples: 
' 
' Download a file: 
'   Url = "https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/ProfileImages/%7Ba82bcf77-ba9f-4ec3-bbb3-1d9ce15cae23%7D.jpg" 
'   FileName = "C:\Test\CodeProjectProfile.jpg" 
'   Result = DownloadFile(Url, FileName) 
' 
' Download a page: 
'   Url = "https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1022704/Rounding-Values-Up-Down-By-Or-To-Significant-Figur?display=Print" 
'   FileName = "C:\Test\CodeProject1022704.html" 
'   Result = DownloadFile(Url, FileName) 
' 
' Error codes: 
' -2146697210   "file not found". 
' -2146697211   "domain not found". 
' -1            "local file could not be created." 
' 
' 2004-12-17. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH. 
' 2017-05-25. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH. Added check for local file. 
' 2017-06-05. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH. Added option to no overwrite the local file. 
' 
Public Function DownloadFile( _ 
    ByVal Url As String, _ 
    ByVal LocalFileName As String, _ 
    Optional ByVal NoOverwrite As Boolean) _ 
    As Long 

    Const BindFDefault  As Long = 0 
    Const ErrorNone     As Long = 0 
    Const ErrorNotFound As Long = -1

    Dim Result  As Long

    If NoOverwrite = True Then 
        ' Page or file should not be overwritten. 
        ' Check that the local file exists. 
        If Dir(LocalFileName, vbNormal) <> "" Then 
            ' File exists. Don't proceed. 
            Exit Function 
        End If 
    End If     

    ' Download file or page. 
    ' Return success or error code. 
    Result = URLDownloadToFile(0, Url & vbNullChar, LocalFileName & vbNullChar, BindFDefault, 0)   

    If Result = ErrorNone Then 
        ' Page or file was retrieved. 
        ' Check that the local file exists. 
        If Dir(LocalFileName, vbNormal) = "" Then 
            Result = ErrorNotFound 
        End If 
    End If   

    DownloadFile = Result 

End Function
```

taken from my article: [Show pictures directly from URLs in Access forms and reports](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html)

(If you don't have an account, browse for the link: Read the full article)

Full code is also at **GitHub**: [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl)

Comment: OP already rejected this approach which ws provided in first comment. I tried this version and get same result.

Comment: @June7: Oh, missed that. But this works for any downloadable file, so if it fails, it is caused by a problem with the site.

Comment: Actually, result is not same. No file is created at all. Function returns -2146697212 - what does that mean?

Comment: @June7: Interesting. What URL did you test? I'm out of the office now, but can check on it in the afternoon.

Comment: Never mind, had a typo in function call. Works with link provided in your code but not with the OPs.

Comment: @June7: OK. Thanks.