# Saving a zipped file, from emails received throughout the day, to the same savefolder

Tags: vba, outlook, unzip, rules

I put this in a rule to automate saving a zipped file I get in emails throughout the day:

```vb
Public Sub SaveZip(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

    Const saveFolder = "C:\Users\Example\Example\Example\"

    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim dName As Variant, unZipFolder

    If itm.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

        unZipFolder = saveFolder & "unzipped\"

        MkDir unZipFolder 

        For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

            dName = objAtt.DisplayName

            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dName

            Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

            oApp.NameSpace(unZipFolder).CopyHere _
              oApp.NameSpace(saveFolder & dName).Items

        Next
    End If     'any attachments
End Sub
```

It works once then won't work for following emails. Nothing happens after the first file is saved and unzipped.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71180518/edit) the question to put in the error message or other result if any.

Comment: Nothing happens after the first file is saved and unzipped

Comment: Either delete `MkDir unZipFolder` or check if existing first [Create folder path if does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658276/create-folder-path-if-does-not-exist-saving-from-vba). A simple, but frowned upon, way https://stackoverflow.com/a/63341029/1571407.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your code under the debugger to understand why it fails. Try to set a break point in the code and see which line of code gives an error message.

Also I'd suggest declaring the parameter as object in the function because incoming items can be different - appointments, mails, non-delivery reports and etc.:

```
itm As Outlook.MailItem
```

You may consider handling the `NewMailEx` event of the Application class instead of having a function called by the rule assigned. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. Use the Entry ID represented by the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

Also I'd suggest adding [On Error statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement) to the code so you could handle errors correctly. You may consider using the `On Error Resume Next` which specifies that when a run-time error occurs, control goes to the statement immediately following the statement where the error occurred and execution continues. Use this form rather than `On Error GoTo` when accessing objects.